# Webpack apply method in HMR

Tags: webpack, hot-module-replacement

I'm reading the [webpack documentation](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/hot-module-replacement/#in-the-runtime).

I have seen this sentence:

> The apply method flags all updated modules as invalid. For each
>   invalid module, there needs to be an update handler in the module or
>   in its parent(s). Otherwise, the invalid flag bubbles up and
>   invalidates parent(s) as well. Each bubble continues until the app's
>   entry point or a module with an update handler is reached (whichever
>   comes first). If it bubbles up from an entry point, the process fails.
>
> Afterwards, all invalid modules are disposed of (via the dispose handler)
>   and unloaded. The current hash is then updated and all accept handlers
>   are called. The runtime switches back to the idle state and everything
>   continues as normal.

Just to be sure I'm understanding the process, so after the updates have loaded, the `apply` function enter in the scene, trying to resolve all the `updated modules`, returning an `error` if no `handler` is found in the process?